# VBA Contains Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, excel, vba

I'm currently making an Excel function that connects to an SQL server and retrieves data as long as it matches the given criteria.

```
Public Function VehModelUnitsCount(VehModel As String, fran As String, Site As Integer, SaleType As String, StartDate, EndDate, New As Integer) As Variant
Application.Volatile
If adoCN Is Nothing Then Call SetUpConnection
Set adoRS = New ADODB.Recordset
EvoStartDate = Format(StartDate, "yyyy/mm/dd")
EvoEndDate = Format(EndDate, "yyyy/mm/dd")
strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) As RCOUNT FROM CARTYPES RIGHT OUTER JOIN CARS ON CARTYPES.Description = CARS.Type LEFT OUTER JOIN CARS2 ON CARS.[Stock Number] = CARS2.[Stock Number]" & Chr(13)
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE (CARTYPES.NewSale =  " & New & " )" & Chr(13)
strSQL = strSQL & "AND (CARTYPES.Franchise = '" & fran & "')" & Chr(13)
strSQL = strSQL & "AND (CARTYPES.Site = " & Site & ")" & Chr(13)
strSQL = strSQL & "AND (CARTYPES.SaleTypeDesc = '" & SaleType & "')" & Chr(13)
strSQL = strSQL & "AND (CARS2.InvoiceDate BETWEEN '" & StartDate & "' AND '" & EndDate & "')" & Chr(13)
strSQL = strSQL & "AND (CARS.Invoiced = '1')" & Chr(13)
Rem strSQL = strSQL & "AND (CARS.Model = '" & VehModel & "')" & Chr(13)
[THIS ONE] - strSQL = strSQL & "AND (CARS.Model CONTAINS '" & VehModel & "')" & Chr(13)
adoRS.Open strSQL, adoCN, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
VehModelUnitsCount = adoRS.Fields("RCOUNT").Value
adoRS.Close
End Function
```

The string marked with [THIS ONE] is the one I am struggling with, I need to find out whether or not the cell **contains** the given string, but apparently using 'CONTAINS' doesn't work.

Any help on completing this would be amazing.

Thank you.

Comment: Try like this : `AND CONTAINS(CARS.Model, '" & VehModel & "')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try -

```
strSQL = strSQL & "AND (CARS.Model LIKE '%" & VehModel & "%')" & Chr(13)
```

Comment: @MoonPunch - If it works as well as your comment suggests, you should click the "Accept" tick mark next to this answer ;)

Comment: I was going to as soon as I read your answer but it told me to wait :) It has been done!